# How to export and import Atlassian Source Tree from one Mac to another?

Tags: mac, import, git

I want to migrate [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) (git client) bookmarks from one Mac to another one.

Is there any easy way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Didn't tested, but the [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) configuration files are on the following path:

> ~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree

Coping the directory to your new computer should be enough to recover your settings.